# dplyr mutate repetitively on a defined number of columns

Tags: dataframe, stringr, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 900 columns. I want to `dplyr::transmute` (e.g., sum) columns 1:3, 4:6, 7:9, and soon for the entire dataframe. The new daughter column names can be created by using text from parent column names, but not matching with others of course. How do I do this?
Thank you very much :)

An example df with 6 columns:

```
int_sam_1 = c("2421432", "24242424", "NA", "4684757849", "NA", "10485040", "NA", 
              "6849400", "40300", "NA", "NA", "NA", "556456466", "4646456466", "246464266", "4564242646")
int_sam_2 = c("NA", "5342353", "14532556", "43566", "46367367", "768769769", "797899", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
              "686899", "7898979", "678568", "NA", "68886", "488")
int_sam_3 = c("11351", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1354151345", "1351351354", "314534", "1535", "3145354", "4353455", 
              "324535", "3543445", "34535", "34535534", "NA", "NA")
int_sam_1a = c("2421432", "24242424", "NA", "4684757849", "NA", "10485040", "NA", 
              "6849400", "40300", "NA", "NA", "NA", "556456466", "4646456466", "246464266", "4564242646")
int_sam_2a = c("NA", "5342353", "14532556", "43566", "46367367", "768769769", "797899", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
              "686899", "7898979", "678568", "NA", "68886", "488")
int_sam_3a = c("11351", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1354151345", "1351351354", "314534", "1535", "3145354", "4353455", 
              "324535", "3543445", "34535", "34535534", "NA", "NA")

df = cbind.data.frame(int_sam_1, int_sam_2, int_sam_3, int_sam_1a, int_sam_2a, int_sam_3a)
```

Comment: Can you add the output you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific need for dplyr, here is a base R solution:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(int_sam_1, int_sam_2, int_sam_3, int_sam_1a, int_sam_2a, int_sam_3a)
df <- data.frame(apply(df,2,as.numeric))
```

create a custom function to apply rowSums or another appropriate function to a subset of 3 columns of df. 'n' is the column index of the first column of the subset

```
fn <- function(df,n) {
    df1 <- data.frame( rowSums(df[,seq(as.numeric(n),as.numeric(n)+2)], na.rm = TRUE) ) 
    colnames(df1) <- paste0(colnames(df[,seq(as.numeric(n),as.numeric(n)+2)]), collapse = '.')
    return(df1)
}
```

sapply over a sequence 1,4,...  (assuming total number of columns are multiples of 3)

```
df2 <- data.frame(sapply(seq(1,ncol(df),3), fn, df = df ))

df2
```

output:

```
      int_sam_1.int_sam_2.int_sam_3      int_sam_1a.int_sam_2a.int_sam_3a
1                        2432783                          2432783
2                       29584777                         29584777
3                       14532556                         14532556
4                     4684801415                       4684801415
5                     1400518712                       1400518712
6                     2130606163                       2130606163
....
```

Comment: Thanks Abhi. Getting this error: Error in seq.default(n, n + 2) : 'from' must be of length 1

Comment: it works in my setup, but my guess is that sapply could be passing the value for n as something other than a number, maybe a named vector. I have replaced n by as.numeric(n) in the code for the function fn. Try it out and let me know. You can also run the code online at https://rdrr.io/snippets/ to see the output